# Keep keyboard always on top & visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I have view with a text field, an image and a few buttons.
I want to make sure the keyboard is displayed and is on top when the view is displayed
AND
I want to make sure it doesn't go away after I type something in to the text field and submit it.

I called `[txtField becomeFirstResponder]` with viewdidload and the keyboard is appearing by default but with a tiny delay after the view is displayed.

Also the becomefirstresponder doesn't help after I have my text field submitted.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Also the becomefirstresponder doesn't help after I have my text field submitted.

That part makes no sense. By default, a text field does not dismiss the keyboard unless *you* dismiss it with `endEditing:` or `resignFirstResponder`. If the keyboard is going away, you must be *making* it go away. So don't and it won't.

EDIT: And indeed, your comment later reveals the answer: you've hooked up the `didEndOnExit` control event from the text field. Well, that causes the keyboard to be dismissed when the user presses the Done button! So you are effectively hitting yourself in the face and then complaining that someone is hitting you in the face.

So the solution, obviously, is *don't* hook up the `didEndOnExit` control event (to anything). Instead, just give the text field a delegate and use the delegate messages to learn what the user is doing. None of those have any automatic behavior with regard to the keyboard, so the keyboard won't be dismissed automatically. For example, to learn when the user is typing, use `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`. To learn when the user has hit the Done button, use `textFieldShouldReturn:`. And so on.

Comment: True, the didEndOnExit is linked to an IBAction that's checking the user input text. However if I don't link it ti didEndOnExit, how can I know when the user finished typing and pressed the done button?

Basically I want to achieve this:
1. Keyboard is visible as the window is loaded
2. User fills in the textfield, presses the DONE button or another button I put next to the field
3. My code checks to see if the string is correct and does some action
4. Meanwhile the focus is still in the text field and the keyboard is still visible

Comment: Yup, well, don't do that. You yourself are doing the thing that you are complaining about. So just stop doing it and the problem will go away. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the answer I'm looking for.
I'll update my code and my entry once I complete what I intended to do.
About hitting myself in the face; I'll probably be doing that for a while now, since I'm only beginning IOS development and OOP.

Comment: @user2292949 I've written a book that might help you; the section on this particular issue is here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch23.html#_text_field_delegate_and_control_event_messages

Comment: @matt what about the use case where a ViewController has a form with a mix of textfields and buttons / selectors.  As the user moves down the form, fills in some text then selects a button option and moves down to the next text field, the keyboard will hop up and down like a kangaroo! This is because, touching the button will make it the first responder.  Can you suggest an elegant solution to this. I ask here because I feel this would be a more complete answer -given the mention of the buttons in the original question